# Android: edit textview defined in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have been sitting for at least 4 hours trying to solve this problem.

To understand this there are 3 files you need to know about:

eggCatcher.java which extends Activity, this class is not used for much more than 
      saving gamestate and showing the optionsmenu.

eggCatcherView.java which extends SurfaceView and contains "the game".

eggCatcher_layout.xml which is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layouten">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <easter.fun.EggCatcherView
            android:id="@+id/eggcatcher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView android:text="Score: " 
                android:id="@+id/totalscore" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
             </TextView>

             <TextView android:text="Bonus: "
                android:id="@+id/bonus" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As shown in the xml file, EggCatcherView is put in the xml file.
When the applications i started the onCreate calls setContentView(layout.eggcatcher_layout);

My question now is:
how can i, from EggCatcherView.java access and edit the TextViews defined in the xmlfile?

if it was in EggCatcher.java it would be easy, just use findViewById(id.bonus), but from
inside the surfaceView appears to be a little more difficult.

I hope i have made everything clear, if you dont understand just ask!

//micke

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the parent view and then from there on you can use `findViewById()` (are you sure you can't just use that method anyway since `SurfaceView` is a subclass of `View` and inherits `findViewById()` from it?).

For using the parent you do something like:

```
ViewParent vp = eggCatcherView.getParent();
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) vp;
TextView tx  = (TextView) fl.findViewById(R.id.bonus);
```

Of course you need to check if the ViewParent is indeed an instance of FrameLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and as you said SurfaceView provides a findViewById(). Unfortunately it does not find the TextView and returns null. If i have got it right findViewById from within a View only will find the childs of that view. I dont know exactly what that means for me. My second theory is that setContentView in onCreate hasn't finnished yet, and its just not possible too find the textViews yet. If thats the case, is there some way to synchronize the constructor in EggCatcherView to wait until setContentView in Eggcatcher has finnished?

Comment: Ok, makes sense with the children.

Answer (score 0):

I found this the best way:

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/test"/>
</LinearLayout>

TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
test.setText("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to access the views in the surrounding activity? That seems like poor architecture. I think it would be better to either pass a callback to the EggCatcherView that can trigger methods in the Activity which in turn operate on the TextViews or fire some kind of events upwards.