# getText() Not Responding

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get the text from one XML to another but it just crashes when its supposed to happen so any help will be welcomed!

Here is the code by the way

```
package com.android.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class xmltwo extends Activity{



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.xmltwo);

            TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            EditText two = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            one.setText(two.getText());
        }


    }
```

That's from the java file that opens the XML where the textView is.

Comment: Try: String s = two.getText(); one.setText(s);

Comment: what does your logcat shows...

Answer (score 3):

My guess?

The logcat will be showing a `NullPointerException` for the line `one.setText(two.getText());` because the layout file referenced by `R.layout.xmltwo` doesn't actually contain a `TextView` with an id of `R.id.textView1` so the `TextView` called `one` is null.

Either that or that layout file doesn't contain an `EditText` with an id of `R.id.editText1` which will make that null and cause an NPE when trying to call `two.getText()`.

Just as an extra bit of information, if you want to get the text from an `EditText` you need to use `getText().toString()`

Comment: Hey the .toString() didnt solved this...
It just shows the same error.
Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In this article [Android: edit textview defined in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059185/android-edit-textview-defined-in-xml) one of the members has a similar issue. They theorize that possibly setContentView hasn't finished running yet and that may be the issue. However, you're saying that it is just completely crashing so I'm not sure if that could be the problem.

Could there be another part of your in your super class that could be hanging up? Could you use the getString() function instead perhaps?

I hope some of this might be helpful! I am interested in finding a solution so I intend to keep on reading to try and help!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  one.setText(two.getText().toString().trim()+"");
```

hope this help..